# WinRT XAML Toolkit Charting Controls: How to style Legend Items?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml, silverlight-toolkit, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I want to style the legend items of the WinRT XAML Toolkit Chart Control.

I checked the source code and found the following style:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:datavis="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization">

    <Style
        TargetType="datavis:Legend">
        <Setter
            Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="Black" />
        <Setter
            Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1" />
        <Setter
            Property="IsTabStop"
            Value="False" />
        <Setter
            Property="TitleStyle">
            <Setter.Value>
                <Style
                    TargetType="datavis:Title">
                    <Setter
                        Property="Margin"
                        Value="0,5,0,10" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="FontWeight"
                        Value="Bold" />
                    <Setter
                        Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                        Value="Center" />
                </Style>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter
            Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate
                    TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                    <Border
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Padding="2">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition
                                    Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <datavis:Title
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                x:Name="HeaderContent"
                                Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                            <ScrollViewer
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                BorderThickness="0"
                                Padding="0"
                                IsTabStop="False">
                                <ItemsPresenter
                                    x:Name="Items"
                                    Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                            </ScrollViewer>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

but this styles the Legend container and Title only.

how can I style the legend items ??

> **EDIT:**
>   Thanks a lot Filip for the answer, this is exactly what I wanted.
>   but Visual Studio gave me an error at:

```
<Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <controls:UniformGrid
                            Columns="1"
                            Rows="5" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
```

it said the **controls:UniformGrid** was not found, I removed this section and managed to get things working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A thing to note first is that the `Legend` control is an `ItemsControl`, so you can style its items using `ItemContainerStyle`. An item template is governed by `LegendItem` style which you can find in the source too. The way to style it all in an application is to set the `Style` of the `Legend` by setting the `LegendStyle` property on the `Chart` control. Then in the `Legend` style set `ItemContainerStyle` to a `Style` of `LegendItem`. I haven't checked if the `Chart` control behaves correctly in Blend, but that would be the best place to edit these if it does. I just handcrafted this sample.

[image]

```
<charting:Chart
    x:Name="PieChart"
    Title="Pie Chart"
    Margin="70,0">
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <Series:PieSeries
            Title="Population"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </charting:Chart.Series>
    <charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
        <Style
            TargetType="datavis:Legend">
            <Setter
                Property="VerticalAlignment"
                Value="Stretch" />
            <Setter
                Property="Background"
                Value="#444" />
            <Setter
                Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <controls:UniformGrid
                            Columns="1"
                            Rows="5" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="TitleStyle">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="datavis:Title">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Margin"
                            Value="0,5,0,10" />
                        <Setter
                            Property="FontWeight"
                            Value="Bold" />
                        <Setter
                            Property="HorizontalAlignment"
                            Value="Center" />
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="ItemContainerStyle"
                xmlns:series="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <Style
                        TargetType="series:LegendItem">
                        <Setter
                            Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate
                                    TargetType="series:LegendItem">
                                    <Border
                                        MinWidth="200"
                                        Margin="20,10"
                                        CornerRadius="10"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        Background="{Binding Background}">
                                        <datavis:Title
                                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                            FontSize="24"
                                            FontWeight="Bold"
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                                    </Border>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter
                Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate
                        TargetType="datavis:Legend">
                        <Border
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Padding="2">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition
                                        Height="Auto" />
                                    <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <datavis:Title
                                    Grid.Row="0"
                                    x:Name="HeaderContent"
                                    Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                    ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                    Style="{TemplateBinding TitleStyle}" />
                                <ScrollViewer
                                    Grid.Row="1"
                                    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                                    BorderThickness="0"
                                    Padding="0"
                                    IsTabStop="False">
                                    <ItemsPresenter
                                        x:Name="Items"
                                        Margin="10,0,10,10" />
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </charting:Chart.LegendStyle>
</charting:Chart>
```